# feature weights for linear SVM (fitcsvm in Matlab)

Tags: matlab, svm, feature-extraction

I have the following implementation of a cross-validated linear SVM. I would like to know which output-variable represents feature weights, and hence relevance of features? In the "cl" variable which stores the parameters of the trained classifier, I find the the variables "W" and "alpha" - as far as I know, alpha represents the classifier coefficients - hence is alpha the variable reflecting the importance of each feature? "W" seems to be almost zero for each entry in my case, while alpha is between 0 and 1 and most often equal to 1.

```
%% SVM-Classification
nrFolds = 10; %number of folds of crossvalidation, 10 is standard
kernel = 'linear'; % 'linear', 'rbf' or 'polynomial'
C = 1; % C is the 'boxconstraint' parameter. Small C = Allow for more missclassif.
solver = 'L1QP';

cvFolds = crossvalind('Kfold', labels, nrFolds);


for i = 1:nrFolds                            % iteratre through each fold
    testIdx = (cvFolds == i);                % indices of test instances
    trainIdx = ~testIdx;                     % indices training instances

    % train the SVM
    cl = fitcsvm(features(trainIdx,:), labels(trainIdx),'KernelFunction',kernel,'Standardize',true,...
    'BoxConstraint',C,'ClassNames',[0,1],'Solver',solver);

    [label,scores] =  predict(cl, features(testIdx,:));
    eq = sum(label==labels(testIdx));
    accuracy(i) = eq/numel(labels(testIdx));

end

crossValAcc = mean(accuracy)
```

Comment: Let me ask you one question: the crossvalidation you are doing, where are you updating it in the SVM model? I find fitcsvm so tricky to use... I don't really understand how to alternate the crossvalidation parameters within the SVM model